# jQuery's extremely low performance while adding rows in a table with Select2

Tags: jquery, html, performance

I'm developing a web page where at the pageload a table is created without rows. With a button, the user can add rows (1 click = 1 more row). The problem is that after about 13-15 rows added, the entire page becomes extremely low; after 80 rows it is completely non-usable.
Since my users will have to add many many rows (even 200-300) I was wondering how can I improve the overall performance.

**EDIT:**
After a while We discovered the problem is caused by Select2, slowing down the page...so how to solve this problem?

```js
var counter = 1;
$('#add').on('click', function() {
  $('#myTable').find('> tbody:last-child').append(
    "<tr id='row" + counter + "'>" +
    "<td>" + counter + "</td>" +
    "<td width='35%'><select id='articolo"+counter+"'></select></td>" +
    "<td width='35%'><select></select></td>" +
    "<td><input type='number'/></td>" +
    "<td><input type='number'/></td>" +
    "<td><input type='number'/></td>" +
    "<td><input type='number'/></td>" +
    "<td><input type='number'/></td>" +
    "<td><input type='text'/></td>" +
    "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-icon waves-effect waves-classic' onclick='removeRow(this)' id='remove" + counter + "'><i class='icon md-delete' aria-hidden='true'></i></button></td>" +
    "</tr>"
  );
$('[id^="articolo"]').select2({ tags: true });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="add">Add</button>
<table id="myTable" data-height="400" data-mobile-responsive="true" class="table table-hover text-center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="text-center">#</th>
      <th class="text-center">Field 1 (*)</th>
      <th class="text-center">Field 2 (*)</th>
      <th class="text-center">Field 3</th>
      <th class="text-center">Field 4</th>
      <th class="text-center">Field 5</th>
      <th class="text-center">Field 6</th>
      <th class="text-center">Field 7</th>
      <th class="text-center">Field 8</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="myTBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It is really strange that it becomes low-performant after adding just 15 rows.

Comment: I placed your example code in a snippet, note I had to include an 'add' button. I've sat for 30 seconds adding hundreds of rows and page performance is absolutely fine. Are you performing any other logic on the appended content?

Comment: Also note that using incremental row `id` attributes is an anti-pattern. You can use common classes on all the rows and DOM traversal to identify them instead.

Comment: In total sincerity I really can't understand why here is fast and on my website it is not...I swear I'm not adding any other element, nor populating the selects...Can just the bootstrap's CSS "break" the magic?

Comment: My jquery version is 2.2.4...do you think this is too old?

Comment: I think showing how this works fast here and slow in your environment, you have your way to find a solution. Take the code as it's here and slowly add what is missing. As soon as it get's slow you'll know what's causing the issue.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I'm really scared I won't find a solution quickly...I'll let you know, for now thank you all

Comment: OK, I found the issue! just below the js block I have a `$('[id^="articolo"]').select2({ tags: true });` ... THIS IS THE PROBLEM, slowing doenw everything...removed that everything works fine...so now my problem is different, I'll edit my question!

Comment: `$('[id^="articolo"]').select2({ tags: true });` this is looking for every instance of `$('[id^="articolo"]')` every time you click, you need to just target the one you just added

Comment: I'd like to give a huge thank you to all of you guys, I would never have been able to achieve this without you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you're targeting all your selects, try this...

Change this:

```
$('[id^="articolo"]').select2({ tags: true });
```

to this:

```
$('#articolo'+counter).select2({ tags: true });
```

That way you're only targeting the last added `select` and not all of them

Comment: WOW MAN, you saved me, literally!! THANK YOU ^^